# Using the DetailsList control and opening a D365 record from a link (CreatorKit)

Tags: dynamics-crm

Link to Microsoft [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/guidance/creator-kit/detailslist)

How to open a record from the detailslist control inside D365 from a custom page.

I see the option to create a column as a link but can't find anything about opening this record.

You can add code to the onChange event:

```
If( Self.EventName = "CellAction",
Notify( "Open Link " &  Self.EventColumn & " " & Self.EventRowKey )
);
```

But how do you navigate to the Model driven app and open that particular record?